# Using the length of the matched group inside regex

Tags: regex, perl

Assume this

```
char=l
string="Hello, World!"
```

Now, I want to replace all `char` in `string` but continuous occurrence (run-length encoding) while reading from `STDIN`

I tried this:

```perl
$c=<>;$_=<>;print s/($c)\1*/length($&)/grse;
```

When the input is given as

```
l
Hello, World!
```

It returns `Hello, World!`. But when I ran this

```perl
$c=<>;$_=<>;print s/(l)\1*/length($&)/grse;
```

it returned `He2o, Wor1d`.

So, since the input is given in separate lines, `$c` contained `\n` (checked with `$c=~/\n/`)
So, I tried

```perl
$c=<>.chomp;$_=<>;print s/($c)\1*/length($&)/grse;
```

and

```perl
$c=<>;$_=<>;print s/($c.chomp)\1*/length($&)/grse;
```

Neither worked. Could anyone please say why?

Comment: `/s` modifier just allows wildcard character `.` to also match newlines. You do not use `.`, hence `/s` modifier is redundant.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Thanks @TLP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Perl, `.` is used to concatenate strings, and not to call methods (unlike in some other languages; Ruby for instance). Have a look at [documentation of `chomp`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp) to see how it should be use. You should be doing

```
chomp($c=<>)
```

Rather than

```
$c=<>.chomp
```

Your full code should thus simply be:

```
chomp($c=<>);$_=<>;print s/($c)\1*/length($&)/grse;
```

If `$c` is always a single character, then the regex can be simplified to `s/$c+/length($&)/grse`. Also, if `$c` can be a regex meta-character (eg, `+`, `*`, `(`, `[`, etc), then it you should escape it (and it makes sense to escape it just in case). To do so, you can use `\Q..\E` (or [`quotemeta`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta), although it is more verbose and thus maybe less adapted to a one-liner):

```
s/\Q$c\E+/length($&)/grse
```

If you don't escape `$c` one way or another, and your one-liner is ran with `(` as first input for instance, you'll get the following error:

```
Quantifier follows nothing in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(+ <-- HERE / at -e line 1, <> line 2
```

---

Regarding what `$c=<>.chomp` actually means in Perl (since this is a valid Perl code that can make sense in some contexts):

`$c=<>.chomp` means `<>` concatenated to `chomp`, where `chomp` without arguments is understood as `chomp($_)`. And `chomp` returns the total number of characters removed, and since `$_` is empty, no characters are removed, which means that this `chomp` returns `0`. So you are basically writing `$c=<>.0`, which means that if your input is `l\n`, you end up with `l\n0` instead of `l`.

One way to debug this kind of this yourself is to:

- Enable warnings with the `-w` flag. In that case, it would have printed

  ```
  Use of uninitialized value $_ in scalar chomp at -e line 1, <> line 1.
  ```

  This is arguably not the most helpful warning ever, but it would have helped you get an idea of where your mistake was.
- Print variables to be sure that they contain what you expect. For instance, you could co `perl -wE '$c=<>.chomp;print"|$c|"'`, which would print:

  ```
  |l
  0|
  ```

  Which should help giving you an idea of what was wrong.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I was indeed golfing using Ruby and Perl and I have never used `chomp` in Perl. This is the first time since all the code would just be subroutines in golfing. I wanted to check the correctness and I wanted to use it.